# How to load google ads after completion of loading the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense, google-tag-manager

I am trying to load the googleads after loading the website. but i am not getting the ads.

Here i am using the Asynchronous rendering by using the [googletag](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag).

how can i do this. is it possible to load the ads after loading of page.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var googletag = googletag || {};
        googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];

    $(window).load(function(){
        (function() {
            var gads = document.createElement('script');
            gads.async = true;
            gads.type = 'text/javascript';
            var useSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
            gads.src = (useSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js';
            var node = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            console.log(node);
            node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
            })();
    });


        function getSamsVisitorCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(window).load(function(){
        var oGoogleDFP = {
                'path' : "<%=navPath_header%>",
                'page' : null,
                'search' : null
            };
            if(location.pathname.indexOf('homepage.jsp')>-1 || location.href == 'http://www.samsclub.com/sams/'){
                oGoogleDFP.path = '/Homepage';
                oGoogleDFP.page = 'main';
            }else if(location.pathname.indexOf('searchResults.jsp')>-1){
                oGoogleDFP.page = 'searchresults';
            }else if(location.pathname.indexOf('.ip')>-1 || location.pathname.indexOf('.cp')>-1){
                oGoogleDFP.path = oGoogleDFP.path.split('/').slice(1); //remove All_Products
                if(location.pathname.indexOf('.ip')>-1) oGoogleDFP.path.pop(); //remove product
                oGoogleDFP.path = (oGoogleDFP.path.length > 4)? '/'+oGoogleDFP.path.slice(0,4).join('/') : '/'+oGoogleDFP.path.join('/');
                oGoogleDFP.page = (location.pathname.indexOf('.ip')>-1)? 'product' : 'main';
            }else if(location.pathname.indexOf('content.jsp')){
                if(location.search.indexOf('pageName=')>-1) oGoogleDFP.path = '/Seasonal/'+location.search.split('pageName=')[1].split('&')[0];
                oGoogleDFP.page = 'seasonal';
            }
            if(location.search.indexOf('searchTerm=')>-1) oGoogleDFP.search = location.search.split('searchTerm=')[1].split('&')[0];
            googletag.cmd.push(function() {
                googletag.defineSlot('/41919049/SamsClub-US'+oGoogleDFP.path, [[1000, 25], [1000, 300]], 'expandableAd').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('page',oGoogleDFP.page).setTargeting('search',oGoogleDFP.search);
                googletag.defineSlot('/41919049/SamsClub-US'+oGoogleDFP.path, [[728, 90]], 'leaderboardTopAd').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('page',oGoogleDFP.page).setTargeting('pos','Top').setTargeting('search',oGoogleDFP.search);
                googletag.defineSlot('/41919049/SamsClub-US'+oGoogleDFP.path, [[728, 90]], 'leaderboardBottomAd').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('page',oGoogleDFP.page).setTargeting('pos','Bottom').setTargeting('search',oGoogleDFP.search);
                googletag.defineSlot('/41919049/SamsClub-US'+oGoogleDFP.path, [[160, 600]], 'skyscraperAd').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('page',oGoogleDFP.page).setTargeting('search',oGoogleDFP.search);
                googletag.defineSlot('/41919049/SamsClub-US'+oGoogleDFP.path, [[300, 250]], 'rectangleAd').addService(googletag.pubads()).setTargeting('page',oGoogleDFP.page).setTargeting('search',oGoogleDFP.search);
                googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();
                googletag.pubads().setTargeting("samsVisitor", getSamsVisitorCookie ("samsVisitor"));
                googletag.enableServices();
            });
    });
```

Comment: can you show us the code where you load the ads into the page?  Are there any errors in your browser's console?

Answer (score 0):

on window.onload event append their js code in head, i hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Ads cannot load unless all of these things are true:

1. The GPT library is loaded.

   - done
2. googletag.defineSlot has been called

   - done
3. The dom has been parsed and includes the ID you specified

   - I put all my scripts in the foot just to be sure
4. googletag.display(slotName) has been called.

   - I don't see this one in your code.

Add the following inside of a googletag.cmd.push but after googletag.enableServices() has been called.

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  googletag.display("expandableAd");
  googletag.display("leaderboardTopAd");
  googletag.display("leaderboardBottomAd");
  googletag.display("skyscraperAd");
  googletag.display("rectangleAd");
});
```